# VBA getElementById with dynamic ID

Tags: dom, vba, getelementbyid

I've been searching this whole forum, msdn and specialised tutorials and I can't find the answer for VBA:
How can I make the `getElementById` work in an access VBA module where the id to find is dynamic?

Let's see the html code:

```
<DIV id=rowToolTipContainer>
<DIV class=contactsCard id=resultsTooltip1122286Contents style="DISPLAY: none">
<TABLE class="shadow-box tooltip">
<TBODY>
```

And how I'm trying to find it:

```
Dim ResultDIV As HTMLDivElement   
Set ResultDIV = HTMLDoc.getElementById("resultsTooltip*")
```

Let me say the html returned has a different id (the numbers change) depending on each result so the id for each DIV is always:

`id=resultsTooltipxxxxxxxContents` where `xxxxxxx` are always different numbers

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this one:

```
Dim ContainerDiv As HTMLDivElement, ResultDIV As HTMLDivElement

Set ContainerDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("rowToolTipContainer")
For Each ResultDIV In ContainerDiv.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    If ResultDIV.ID Like "resultsTooltip*Contents" Then

        '' What do you want to do here?

        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought you were suggesting. I'll come back to you once I test it. Many thanks, Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the closest parent tag that always contains the ID (manually, by looking at your HTML).
2. Enumerate all descendant `<div>`s of that tag, testing their `ID` property with `Like`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure if I understand you: The ID is only contained inside the mentioned DIV... I guess your idea is to get a parent tag and then enumerate the descendant div tags as you mention, right?

Comment: its been 8 years since this was asked, and im struggling with this now, what if the container has dynamic numbers too like :  PRMT_SV_CONTAINER_******************_NS_??  and even worse, the class is ""(literraly double quotes "" meaning nothing!!!, then the div is dynamic too = PRMT_SV_******************_NS_ and the thing i need to click is only: <option value = "TEXT INCLUDED BEFORE" </option>   XD i just need a way to click the option 0 inside that container...

Comment: @GaboWalker Then threat the `<body>` tag as the parent div and apply the same logic to find the `PRMT_SV_CONTAINER_` with `Like`. Having found it, apply the same logic to it to find `PRMT_SV_******************NS` inside it with `Like`...

Comment: hey GSerg, thanks a lot, however i just cant make it work, i created a new question to try to solve my issue, if you have a minute and want to take a look here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309608/click-on-a-website-element-inside-a-container-with-dynamic-ids-vba-excel