# How to add a tick to a checkbox through excel vba ie automation?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

The checkbox I am trying to add a tick to is part of an online table and doesn't seem to be coded as a checkbox.

I have tried the following to add a tick and none work:

```
IE.Document.getElementByID("gridcolumn-1658-titleEl").Click

IE.Document.getElementByID("gridcolumn-1658-textEl").Click

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("x-column-header-inner x-column-header-over")(0).Click

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("x-column-header-inner")(0).Click
```

When I inspect the element, I get to the following, but none of this looks anything like a checkbox (the third one is the actual reference):

```
<div class="x-column-header x-column-header-checkbox x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-column-header-first" style="border-width: 1px; width: 24px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 24px;" id="gridcolumn-1658"><div id="gridcolumn-1658-titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;"><span id="gridcolumn-1658-textEl" class="x-column-header-text">&nbsp;</span></div></div>

<div id="gridcolumn-1658-titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;"><span id="gridcolumn-1658-textEl" class="x-column-header-text">&nbsp;</span></div>

<span id="gridcolumn-1658-textEl" class="x-column-header-text">&nbsp;</span>
```

The website is OptimoRoute, which can be accessed fairly quickly using a new log in, for those interested!

The button I am trying to click is the top one in the table.

Comment: Does the box check/uncheck when clicked with the mouse?  What about when you tab to the checkbox and then press the space bar?

Comment: Try getting to the checkbox with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048940/vba-getelementbyid-with-dynamic-id and then once you get to the element, try ResultDiv.Checked = True

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
Sub main()
    'we define the essential variables

    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Dim ticket As String


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("https://dillion132.github.io/vbacheckbox.html")

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set Data = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("check")

        Debug.Print Data.Length

        If Len(Data) > 0 Then
            For Each ee In Data

                'Debug.Print ee.Value

                'Based on the checkbox value to check/uncheck the checkbox.
                If ee.Value = "Cat" Then

                   ee.Checked = True

                End If

                'check whether the checkbox is checked, then, get the checked value.
                If ee.Checked Then
                   Debug.Print ee.Value & " is checked"

                End If
            Next ee

        End If
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code in the website:

```
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="Cat"> Cat </input>
<br />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="Dog"  >Dog</input> 
<br />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="Pig" checked ="checked" >Pig</input>
```

The result as below:

[image]